# Who was "The Phantom Menace"?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

This might seem ridiculous, but I realised that, years after I watched the film, I've still no idea to whom the title was referring. Who was it?

- Anakin - not realising his hidden (phantom) side?
- Darth Maul - an unknown character, stalking phantom-like after Anakin?
- Palpatine - hiding (again, like a phantom) his true intentions?
- Jar Jar Binks - as [theorised in this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=8yy3q9f84EA)?

Seriously - who was "The Phantom Menace"?

Comment: I am following the lead another user made on my Phantom Menace question, and I believe it makes sense (yours is the only one I added). Given how tags are used for filtering or searching, its not really a tautology.  Please note that questions relating to other movies are tagged with star-wars, so my addition of the tag to this question is entirely consistent with how it is used on the site.

Comment: If only Jar-Jar had been subtle enough to be considered a phantom.

Comment: @Beofett: thanks. Shame we can't do some kind of "sub-tag" because this really is double.

Comment: I think the tag for the contest is what is creating the redundancy. Then again, there's enough hate for the prequels that some might want to check star-wars questions, but skip phantom-menace ones.

Comment: Obi-Wan Kenobi...

Comment: It refers to the movie's fight choreography: [never let any hint of menace be shown - the menace must be phantom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0mUVY9fLlw)

Comment: Why do you assume it was a person, and not a situation?  Definition of "menace":a person or thing that is likely to cause harm; a threat or danger.  The Phantom Menace is not a person, but the overall situation that was created which resulted in Palpatine's rise to Chancellor.

Comment: @DaveJohnson: want to make that into an answer?

Comment: @Wikis: want to mark it accepted? - It's not who; it's *what*.

Comment: @Mazura: ideally I'd like a quote by Lucas or someone to *prove* an answer rather than speculation.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/102167/4918 Which wars are “Star Wars”?

Comment: I think the Phantom Menace refers to George Lucas.  Giving him free reign in filmmaking was the greatest threat to the Galaxy Far, Far Away.

Comment: Related: [Why is the movie titled The Phantom Menace?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78741/49)

Answer (score 82):

**Simple Version**: The actual phantom menace was the one Palpatine/Sidious created merely for the sake of taking over the Senate.

The point, and using the name *The Phantom Menace* just emphasizes it, is that the threat to Naboo may be real, but it's secondary to Palpatine's real goal, which is to make Naboo feel threatened (or menaced) so it was easy for Palpatine to manipulate the Senate into doing what he wanted.

**More In Depth Version**:  Since Palpatine controlled the Separatists (I'm including the Trade Federation with them) through Dooku (without anyone knowing it), he was able to order a blockade around Naboo.  Since it was his own homeworld, that would also help with appearances when he showed any extra concern to help break the blockade.

His whole goal was for Amidala to plead in front of the Senate and for there to be enough sympathy for her cause (and him being from that same planet gave him sympathy points, as well) that when she asked for help and Chancellor Velorum was able to only give her standard rhetoric, Senators would be behind her when she moved for a vote of no confidence.

His entire goal was to put Amidala in such a vulnerable position that people would support her when she asked for a vote of no confidence.  Then, once that happened, it would be easy for him to manipulate the sympathy and concern into votes to elect himself as Chancelor.

While he was interested in Naboo, that was not nearly as important as becoming the Chancellor, which would put him in a position to eventually take control of the Senate.  Even though Palpatine had other plans for Naboo, what mattered most was the issue in the Senate.

Comment: Palpatine **had intention of hurting Naboo**, [his plan was to have the federation Invade Naboo](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5624/why-did-the-trade-federation-blockade-naboo). He would not had sent Darth Maul otherwise.

Comment: Either way, Naboo wasn't nearly as important as the takeover of the Senate.

Comment: Agreed, but it was still part of the plan. He must have made some adjustment after the death of Darth Maul / failure of the invasion.

Comment: @DavRob60: I won't have time to edit it for another 8 hours, since I'll be out.  I'll edit it when I get back.  (If you want to make that change before that, I won't have a problem with it.)

Comment: So are you saying that "The Phantom Menace" was a fake attack on Naboo?

Comment: I always saw it as a political commentary, a play on 'The Red Menace' The 'Phantom' Menace struck me as a term for a diversionary menace; paying attention to something unreal (totally created by Palpatine) kept the attention on it, instead of people being more alarmed by his rise to greater and greater power / elimination of check & balances, etc.   Think how well a sudden burst of McCarthyism (initiated by someone else, of course) would have covered Clinton's butt with the whole Monica Lewinski issue.  The public likes things juicy.. and the Naboo Blockade and related stuff fit the bill.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff How do you figure that either of the other answers imply that "phantom" means "fake"? Both indicate clearly that it is Palpatine because he is "hidden" behind the scenes. This answer, before the edits (good edits, btw), indicated that the threats to Naboo were "fake".

Comment: @Beofett: sorry; got words mixed up; let's try again: Given that "phantom" means "fake", this answer makes more sense than those that state that Palpatine is the menace, as they imply that "phantom" means "hidden", which is not the case.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff "Phantom" can mean "[something elusive or deceptive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/phantom)", which can mean "[tending to elude perception](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elusive)". But even if we agree that "phantom" means "fake", nothing about the threat to Naboo was "fake" (the blockade and invasions were both very real). They were misdirections designed to hide Palpatine's real goals, and manipulate people into supporting those goals, but they were not fake.  I'm in [chat] if you'd like to discuss this further.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff: Seriously, considering the screenwriter for this, what matters is what Lucas wants "phantom" to mean, but if you insist on carrying this farther, can it be done in chat?

Comment: @Beofett: See above ^^^^

Comment: Creating a Phantom Menance is an old political tactic.                                       
"To make the wrong appear the right,                                                               
 And keep our rulers in.
In Walpole's time, 'twas Jacobite,
In Pitt's, 'tis Jacobin! "                                                                                 
Edward Coxe  1805   -  https://historum.com/threads/jacobite-jacobin.125989/

Answer (score 37):

There's a subtle shift of focus (that is, literal *camera* focus) at the end of the movie that illustrates who the Phantom Menace is.  It comes soon after Yoda's line:

> Always two, there are. No more, no less. A master... and an apprentice.

Shortly after this line, the camera refocuses onto the Phantom Menace, revealed to be:

> Palpatine

Comment: Always two, there are. And only the sith deal in absolutes.

Comment: But how do we know that *is* "The Phantom Menace"?

Comment: The timing of the change in focus makes it pretty clear that this is the question it was intended to answer.  It really is fairly subtle; I only noticed it the second time I watched the movie.  (Don't ask me how I managed to sit through it twice.)

Comment: Yes, I spotted that as well, but as I said to @Beofett, I don't get how this refers to The Phantom Menace. Did someone say, *"The Phantom Menace"* just before this camera pan?

Comment: @Wikis, I could be mistaken, but I don't recall anyone uttering the phrase "Phantom Menace" *anywhere* in the film.  Exact wording doesn't always have to be present for a concept to be present.

Comment: @Kyralessa: I completely agree but I don't get how one camera pan at the end *automatically implies* that it is referring to the title. Is it me?! Am I missing something *really* obvious?

Comment: @Wikis I believe "process of elimination" is a valid rationale.  The threat to Naboo TangoOversway mentions in his answer is neither hidden, nor illusionary (there is a very real blockade and invasion). It is a misdirection, but I don't see how misdirection can be tied to the term "phantom" in this case.  However, it is very clear that Palpatine is manipulating things from behind the scenes, *hiding* his true motives.  Palpatine's secret identity as a Sith Lord and his motives are the only things hidden in the movie.

Comment: [According to the databank this is the correct answer](http://www.starwars.com/databank/emperor-palpatine-darth-sidious).

Answer (score 18):

According to George Lucas in ["The Force Is Back"](https://www.vanityfair.com/news/1999/02/star-wars) (by David Kamp, *Vanity Fair*, February 1999):

> Given that *The Phantom Menace* is a Vader- and Emperor-free movie, the
>   role of evil string-puller falls to someone we’ve never heard of. **“The
>   phantom menace is a character named Darth Sidious,”** Lucas says, “who
>   is the last of the Sith” (“An ancient people . . . conquered by
>   powerful dark-side Jedi magic”—page 268, *Star Wars Encyclopedia*, by
>   Stephen J. Sansweet). **Actually, Lucas goes on to explain, the “menace”
>   honorific should be broadened to include Sidious’s apprentice, Darth
>   Maul**, a terrifyingly fierce-looking character played by the
>   martial-arts expert Ray Park.

Answer (score 12):

The Phantom Menace was the Sith Master the Jedi council realized must be behind the scenes, pulling the strings:

> **Yoda**: Always two there are, no more, no less. A master and an apprentice.
>
> **Mace Windu**: But which was destroyed, the master or the apprentice?

Comment: How do you know "The Phantom Menace" refers to "the Sith Master... behind the scenes"?

Comment: I watched the movie. You don't really need a reference from the "always reliable" Wikipedia to interpret the title.

Comment: I know you don't need Wikipedia but your answer doesn't convince me that the title refers to Palpatine. Sorry.

Comment: Normally I would say "okay" and move on, but I find it odd that you are making this comment when your answer is in no way significantly different than mine, other than a vague wikipedia reference whose wording doesn't make clear if Lucas confirmed the meaning of the title, or simply that the working title was *The Phantom Menace* (the wording seems to me that Lucas confirmed the working title, and not the meaning).

Comment: Perhaps we can discuss this further in chat?

Comment: No problem. Now is inconvenient for me. :( Let's try chat later this week, OK?

Comment: @Wikis Sure.  I should be around chat off and on until this weekend.

Comment: Wouldn't the actual Sith Master be a real menace?

Comment: @Oldcat "Phantom" doesn't necessarily mean "not real".  It can (and I think in this case, does) mean "hidden or unseen".

Answer (score 7):

[Wikipedia confirms the Palpatine theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phantom_Menace#Writing) that others have mentioned in their answers:

> While the working title for the film was The Beginning, Lucas later revealed the true title to be The Phantom Menace; a reference to Palpatine hiding his true identity as an evil Sith Lord behind the facade of a well-intentioned public servant.

Comment: Wikipedia never *confirms* anything.

Comment: @JackBNimble *Nothing* ever confirms anything. Well, nothing other than math, that is.

Comment: If this were so, shouldn't the name be "The Hidden Menace"?  Phantoms aren't real.

Answer (score 7):

According to [the official Star Wars databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/emperor-palpatine-darth-sidious), it's Palpatine.

From his character bio [emphasis mine]:

> Scheming, powerful, and evil to the core, Darth Sidious restored the Sith and destroyed the Jedi Order. Living a double life, **Sidious was in fact Palpatine, a Naboo Senator and phantom menace.** He slowly manipulated the political system of the Galactic Republic until he was named Supreme Chancellor -- and eventually Emperor -- ruling the galaxy through fear and tyranny.

Answer (score 2):

A phantom menace also means an unknown evil. In the film, two major unknown evils include:

1) Senator Palpatine hiding his Sith Lord and (later) Galactic Emperor persona and

2) young Anakin (later to become Darth Vader).

Darth Maul could even be considered a phantom menace because no one knows who he is and where he came from. In my opinion however, I believe that the "real" phantom menace (title of the film is 'The' Phantom Menace, therefore there is only one) is Anakin Skywalker. The point of the two trilogies was to tell the story of Anakin's life and death. It makes sense for the first episode in the series to retroactively introduce the young Anakin while the audience was fully aware of his (evil) future.

Answer (score 2):

**The Phantom Menace is not a person, but a reference to the overall situation that the characters find themselves in throughout the movie.**

Though we have several villains in the movie:

- Darth Plageous
- Darth Sidious
- Darth Maul
- The Trade Federation
- The Separatists

Menace is defined simply as

> a person or thing that is likely to cause harm; a threat or danger.

Sometime during the film, but off-screen, the Clone Army is ordered:

> OBI-WAN: Yes, Master. They say Master Sifo-Dyas placed the
>   order for a clone army at the request of the Senate almost ten years
>   ago. I was under the impression he was killed before that. Did the
>   Council ever authorize the creation of a clone army?
>
> MACE WINDU: No. Whoever placed that order did not have the
>   authorization of the Jedi Council.
>
> <sub>[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5777/14710), talking about Episode II</sub>

We know that this was done so that the Empire would have an army to use later.  The use of this army must be justified, though, as it has been a long time since the Republic had a standing army.  As such, the Sith must create an environment in which no one will even blink when they destroy the Republic in favor of the Empire, and adopt this army.

How does one precipitate the chain of events that need to take place to see the rise of Palpatine and the Empire?  By creating fear and confusion, and manipulating those most affected by said fear and confusion into pushing events forward.

This is largely accomplished with the blockade of Naboo.  This directly results in Palpatine becoming the Supreme Chancellor, as Queen Amadalla herself calls for a vote of No Confidence in the current Chancellor, an action for which Palpatine is already prepared with votes to gain the position.

Even though the main villain is definitely Palpatine, we can safely assume that The Phantom Menace is simply the menace of the situation, the origins of which are hidden from the Jedi and the Senate, as well as the galaxy at large.

Comment: Plus one, *"Phantoms aren't real."* –Oldcat, commenting on another answer here. I was looking for a way to upvote just because of your name, but you also happened to have the only correct answer here. BTW, how's that reactor coming?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I have a weird view of things, but I always saw the *The Phantom Menace* not as a person, but as a concept in general.

Think about what Darth Sidious' plan was all along, he wanted to rule the galaxy. The way he devised to do that, was to convince the republic to vote him chancellor and to vote to give him "emergency powers".

The way he chose to do this, was to make the republic feel like it was threatened, so that it would be forced to accept the clone army(which later become the main soldiers for the empire) and by voting for a chancellor and giving him powers they thought were needed in order to defend the galaxy.

Remembering a definition of Phantom:

> a figment of the imagination.

And the defintion of Menace:

> a person or thing that is likely to cause harm; a threat or danger.

Sidious created a fake threat, the separtists and their rebellion,  to make the republic think they were being threatened so that they would do what he wanted, put him in power.

So *The Phantom Menace* is in fact, the false threat Sidious invented to manipulate the senate and the republic.

Answer (score 0):

I always thought it referred to Darth Maul, but I may be wrong. However, I have not been convinced otherwise as of yet. Darth Maul was stalking Qui-Gon and the others on Tatooine like a phantom, with his Sith macrobinoculars, probe droids and what not. He certainly proved to be a menace when he stabbed Qui-Gon with a [badass] double-bladed Sith lightsaber.

Comment: Interesting ideas, but please improve this answer by adding references.

Comment: Darth Maul was as effective as a phantom. That's true.