# Where is the image suggesting sub-title meanings for each Star Wars flm?

Tags: star-wars

I saw an image online somewhere that showed the meaning of all 7 *Star Wars* movie titles.

For example, for *The Phantom Menace* it showed the scene where Palpatine is first seen as a hologram.

Does anyone know where I can find that image that shows in scenes the meaning of each title from all 7 movies?

Comment: I think http://movies.stackexchange.com/ can in this instance help out more than here.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10542/4918 "Who was “The Phantom Menace”?"

Comment: in the future, do not crosspost the same question to multiple stacks. if you want it moved, flag it and requests the mods to do so.

Comment: @yondaime008 why do you think movies would be a better fit for starwars then the sci-fi site?

Comment: I thought so, because this is more of a search of media related to the movie than a scifi or fantasy question. I may be extremely wrong though.

Comment: @yondaime008 while that logic may be good for most movies, any major sci-fi/fantasy movie, will most likely get a better answer, and a faster answer over here, because of our mass of people specialized in all aspects of sci-fi, especially 100s of people who love star wars, vs a few over in movies.

Comment: @Himarm agreed !

Comment: It doesn't seem a particularly fitting question on any of the two sites, though. It just seems like a request for finding some arbitrary random fan image on the web. And it's a bit unclear in the first place.

Comment: @TARS I agree as well, but... it kind of makes me wish for a stack exchange site about internet memes :)