# Why is the Trade Federation interested in Naboo?

Tags: star-wars

Why was the Trade Federation so interested in Naboo? Why did they blocked Naboo especially since it's a small planet and apparently unimportant.

Comment: technically, the other question asks from the other side of the coin, but the answer there explains this.

Comment: Yesterdat night I was very tired and I didn't realise what I asked. These is the question that I wanted to post.

Comment: see also: [Why did the Trade Federation blockade Naboo?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5624/5184)

Answer (score 4):

**Because they were coerced into doing this by Palpatine / Sidious.**

Senator Palpatine hails from Naboo. He needed Naboo on the center stage in order for him to gain the much-needed sympathy votes to influence the voting for the replacement of Chancellor Valorum. To that end, as Sidious, he influenced the Viceroy of the Trade Federation to set up the blockade around -and even invade- Naboo.

From Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palpatine):

> In The Phantom Menace, the character is depicted as a middle-aged
>   Galactic Senator from the planet Naboo who is secretly the Sith Lord
>   Darth Sidious. As Sidious, he influences the corrupt Trade Federation
>   to blockade and invade Naboo. Queen Padmé Amidala of Naboo flees to
>   the planet Coruscant to receive counsel from Palpatine, unaware that
>   he actually engineered the invasion. After a plea for help from the
>   senate results in bureaucratic delays, Palpatine persuades the queen
>   to make a motion to have Supreme Chancellor Finis Valorum removed from
>   office.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, all is very clear in my head. :))